# In what cases will PHP's error suppression not work for undefined indexes?

Tags: php, exception

I'm using a library via composer that has code like this:

```php
$data['video_id'] = @$data['video_id'] ?: $player['videoId'];
```

This line is causing a `500` error because `$data['video_id']` is not defined. If I remove the `@` symbol, I get the exception `Notice: Undefined index: video_id`. If I put back the `@` symbol, the script simply dies immediately, and nginx returns a 500 status.

[PHP's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) says:

> Warning: Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

It's possible this is happening here, but the error is not critical: it is a "notice", and according to that documentation, is a valid use for `@`.

I can always fork this library and fix the error myself, but I'd like to know why the suppression variable isn't working as intended.

Comment: I think what really is of note is this is the wrong approach. You should be using the [Null colascing operator (`??`)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) here. `$data['video_id'] = $data['video_id'] ?? $player['videoId'];`. In PHP 7.4 it will be able to be shortened to `$data['video_id'] ??= $player['videoId'];`.

Comment: Do you have a user defined error handler that may be exiting on error?

Comment: above is very useful but might have issues depending on the value of that field because it uses [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#119993). I would just wrap `$data['video_id']` with `array_key_exists`.

Comment: @IronMan the default symfony error handler is being used, and I don't believe it is suppressing any errors. It logs all errors.

Comment: @JohnConde as I stated in my post, I'm aware of how to fix it. My question is why the @ suppressor isn't working correctly.

Comment: Unlike `??` the `@` operator does not suppress logging for undefined vars. If the Symfony handler trips over sending it to the log, then that's where the 500 originated.

Comment: @mario after digging into the error handler, I found the issue there: there was a custom monolog processor that wasn't handling the error correctly. Feel free to post this as an answer!